# How can I select only specific columns from database instead of removing them later?

Tags: powerbi

My existing code is but it takes too much of the time

```
let
Source = Oracle.Database("orcl", [HierarchicalNavigation=true]),
NOVA_SHF = Source{[Schema="NOVA_SHF"]}[Data],
GL_VCHRDETAIL1 = NOVA_SHF{[Name="GL_VCHRDETAIL"]}[Data],
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(GL_VCHRDETAIL1,{"VD_PST_TAG", "VD_BANK_STNO", "VD_COSTCNTR_CODE", "VD_QUANTITY", "VD_PARTY_CODE"})
```

in
#"Removed Columns"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your can specify an SQL Query to SELECT your columns in the Oracle.Database() options: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/oracle-database.

However, you can also specify an SQL in in the Get Data UI:

[image]